# Get Values from comma separated ids as foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have two tables

a> tutors
b> subject

In the tutor table, I have values as 1,2 in "tutor.tut_subjects_id" field which are primary ids of the subject table where 1 and represent two different subjects namely Mathematics and Physics.

I am using the following code to display the number of subjects for each tutor

In controller file:

```php
    $feat_tuts = DB::table('tutors')
    ->join('subject', 'tutors.tut_subjects_id', '=', 'subject.id')
    ->where('tutors.tut_feat', 'yes')
    ->get(); 

return view('Frontend/pages/home',compact(['allcategories','feat_courses','feat_tuts']));
```

In Blade file:

```php
    @foreach($feat_tuts as $each_feat_tuts)
    {{$each_feat_tuts->name}}
    @endforeach
```

But I am getting only one Data i.e "Mathematics" from the subject table.

I need to know how to show two data from the subject table which are Mathematics and Physics.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1st you need to add a relationship one to many then from you can `pluck('name')` of subject and `join(',')` with comma

Comment: I can do the relation in model but for pluck('name') and join(',') if you help me by writing the whole code that would be nice. Sorry, I am asking for the code because I am new to Laravel.

Comment: `$tutors->subjects->pluck('name')->join(',')` if you set `subjects()` to `tutors` model

Answer (score 0):

$feat_tuts = \DB::table('tutors')
->select('tutors.*',\DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(subject.name) as subject_name"))
->leftjoin('subject',\DB::raw("FIND_IN_SET(subject.id, tutors.tut_subjects_id)"),">",\DB::raw("'0'"))
->where('tutors.tut_feat', 'yes')
->groupBy('tutors.id')
->get();

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it